# REACT. Доступ к картинкам через стили

Tags: css, reactjs, scss

Всех приветствую. Очень плохо объясняю, но вопрос очень интересует. Подскажите пожалуйста, видел примеры, где в стилях находящихся в файловой системе react-а, а именно в папке src (стили находились рядом с компонентами), прописывали к примеру такой путь :

```
$img-dir-path: '/img/';
background-image: url('#{$img-dir-path}event.png');
```

Но по факту, данная папка img находится в public. И примерно должен был получиться такой путь :

```
background-image: url('../../../public/img/event.png');
```

Если писать в jsx разметке такой путь:

```
<img src="img/main-bg.jpg" alt="" className={styles["main-page__img"]}/>
```

То компонента, как раз таки имеет доступ к картинкам относительно папки public. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно настроить react, чтобы пути искались не относительно файла стилей, где он находится, а относительно папки public (на примере того как это делает компонента).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Связано всё с обновлением react-scripts от 4+ версии. Чтобы пофиксить данную проблему, по этому пути node_modules/react-scripts/config/ ищем файл webpack.config.js и на 123 строке меняем с options: cssOptions, на  options: {...cssOptions, url: false}, . С react-scripts ниже 4 версии (3.4.x) всё работает как надо. Ссылки на решение:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9870
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57111197/react-path-to-public-folder-in-css-background-image